# Branching out domain topographs

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

I'm reading an illustrated theory of numbers by Martin H. Weissman, on page-233, it is shown how to expand out a domain topograph starting from basis $\pm (17,12)$ and $\pm(7,5)$

[image]

I understand that the basis idea is that if $\{v,w\}$ are independent, then so are $\{v+w,w\}$ and $\{v-w,w \}$. But, I don't understand how the above was expanded further:

[image]

How did we get the blue edges from the greens?

Comment: See answer by Will Jagy [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285989/88984)